# Trying to understand how to add more hidden layers into a neural network using a for loop

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I'm trying to figure out how would I make a simple for loop to add more hidden layers to this neural network for the basic tensorflow neural network from the code below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

normally I would go ahead and change the following code:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])
```

and add more layers.Dense as follow:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])
```

Is it possible to create a simple for loop where I can input the number of hidden layers I want?

Comment: The arguement you passed into the constructor of the Sequential model is an array. You can iterate over the array and add tf.keras.layers.Dense layer objects to the array.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal can you perhaps show me an example of how to do it?

Comment: @Chris I am getting error when I add more than 3 layers. Error code shown below :
`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [7000,2], In[1]: [100,1]
  [[{{node dense_3/BiasAdd}}]]
`
I am having these layers :
`keras.layers.Dense(100, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu, input_shape=(7,)),
keras.layers.Dense(100, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu),
keras.layers.Dense(100, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu),
keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid)`

Answer (score 0):

First, create an `list` object and add a `Flatten` layer to it.

```
layers = list()
layers.add( tf.keras.layers.Flatten() )
```

Now, we use a loop statement to add `n` number of `Dense` layers.

```
units = [ 64 , 128 , 256 ]

for i in range( n ):
    layers.add( tf.keras.layers.Dense( units[i] , activation='relu' ) )
```

Where `n` could be any positive integer.